# Give examples of a basis of $L^1([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

In particular, are there any countable bases of $L^1([0,1])$?

Comment: Yes, take for example the Haar basis consisting of functions of the form $h_I=\chi_{I_l}-\chi_{I_r}$ where $I$ is a standard dyadic interval and $I_l$, $I_r$ its left, respectively right child intervals.

Comment: Any Hamel basis of an infinite dimensional Banach space is uncountable. For a Schauder basis, see the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take for example the [Haar basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) consisting of functions of the form $h_I=\chi_{I_l}-\chi_{I_r}$ where $I$ is a standard dyadic interval and $I_l$, $I_r$ its left, respectively right child intervals and $\chi_I$ are (depending on your needs, properly normalized) characteristic functions.

This constitues a countable (Schauder) basis for $L^p([0,1])$ when $p\ge 1$ and $p<\infty$.

Comment: To make sure I got the idea, I made a drawing. Is this how would the functions look like?
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1WaAOB524J1ypMsYCVtfZx9zSLTaN3EHT73btMQaVU5I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The first one is exactly $ h_{[0,1]} $. Regarding the other two drawings; these are sums of Haar functions.